# g5.48xlarge on-demand instance creation failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I try to launch a g5.48xlarge instance on AWS. But it says the configuration is not supported.

My configuration is:

- **Region:** US-WEST-2
- **AMI:** Amazon certified image, explicitly saying it support the G5 instance. The name is "Deep Learning AMI GPU CUDA 11.1.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) 20230211" (ami-076342b82eaef5e5c)
- **Networking:** default firewall; no preference on availability zone
- **Storage:** 2200 GB gp3 storgage (IOPS set to 6600)

The error message is `The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.` I have checked the instance type is available in this region. Can anyone help? Thank you.

I tried in US-EAST-1, tried GP2, IO1, IO2 storage types. None of them worked. I would like to get a G5.48xlarge on-demand instance as my machine for developing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your service quotas

- Running On-Demand G and VT instances

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home

Comment: Please explain what should be done after checking the quotas to actually solve the problem. This might be obvious to you but won't be for everyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).